# Merge the queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two set of queries which is shown below i need to merge the queries in terms of some circumstances which is specified below.

```
SELECT  M.Ward_ID ,
        M.Ward_Name ,
        M.Bed_Strength ,
        M.Bed_Strength - ISNULL(COUNT(A.WARD_id), 0) AS Free_Bed ,
        ISNULL(COUNT(A.Status), 0) AS TBV
FROM    Ward_Master M
        LEFT OUTER  JOIN IP_Admission A ON A.WARD_ID = M.WARD_ID
                                           AND ( A.Status = 'O' )
                                           OR A.Status IN ( SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), COUNT(A.Status)) AS TBV
                                                            FROM    Ward_Master w ,
                                                                    IP_Admission a
                                                            WHERE   a.Status = 'D'
                                                                    AND a.Ward_ID = w.Ward_ID )
GROUP BY M.Ward_ID ,
        M.Bed_Strength ,
        M.Ward_Name ,
        A.Status
```

Output is like

```
       Ward_ID        Ward_Name         Bed_Strength Free_Bed   TBV
           1           Labor                  6          4       2
           2           GYN                    6          5       1
           3           OBG                    6          6       0
           4           High Ri                6          4       2
           5           PED                   14         14       0
```

2)

```
SELECT  ward_ID ,
        COUNT(status)
FROM    IP_Admission
WHERE   Status = 'D'
GROUP BY Ward_ID
```

output:

```
ward_ID (No column name)
   2    1
   3    1
   5    2
```

Now I need the first table to be converted as

```
     Ward_ID     Ward_Name   Bed_Strength    Free_Bed    TBV
       1           Labor           6           4          0
       2           GYN             6           5          1
       3           OBG             6           6          1
       4           High Ri         6           4          0
       5           PED             14          14         2
```

You can see that for ward ID **2,3,5** there are **1,1,2** total number of status having `D`. And also if any Ward_ID which doesnt contain `status count` it should display `0`.Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems clear to me from looking at your query that you don't completely understand why you're getting the results that you are; you kept on tacking on additional parts to the query, which has resulted in your current question here.

First, some notes:

```
GROUP BY M.Ward_ID ,
         M.Bed_Strength ,
         M.Ward_Name ,
```

Generally speaking, if your `GROUP BY` starts off with a unique column for a given table, and then lists non-key attributes for that table it's a sign you want to pre-aggregate results from other tables (subquery table references).  This will (almost always) make your query consume fewer resources in two ways:

1. It's unlikely that an index (which are used to speed up access to data) would or *should* be created for the given columns you're using, which means the query is unlikely to use one.
2. You're doing an unnecessary `GROUP BY` which includes columns that should already be unique.  The temporary set of results will be larger than it should be

   ```
        A.Status
   ```

You're also including a column in the `GROUP BY` that you *don't* list as a non-aggregate column.  This is the equivalent to a teacher averaging the grades of his students by gender, and then not stating which average belongs to which group; it renders the data meaningless.  There's almost never a reason to do this.

```
ISNULL(...)
```

.... *does* do what you want.  However, it's preferable to use the SQL Standard `COALESCE(...)` function instead.

```
ON A.WARD_ID = M.WARD_ID
   AND ( A.Status = 'O' )
   OR A.Status IN (...)
```

**EVERY** time you mix `OR`s with *anything* else, wrap the intended compound statements in parentheses.  The computer is a blind idiot, and will do whatever it *thinks* you told it to do.  So for your own sake (and those who come after you), always explicitly clarify what you mean in these situations

```
CONVERT(...)
```

While this is likely doing what you want, it's preferable to use another SQL Standard function here, `CAST(...)`.  The equivalent statement here would be `CAST(COUNT(A.Status)) as VARCHAR(1))`... however:

1. The only advantage a `VARCHAR(1)` has over a `CHAR(1)` is that it could *not* store a single whitespace character.
2. Given the statuses you've provided are all character, I *really* doubt that any of the codes are numeric
3. You don't even have the control over the results you think you do, because...

   SELECT  COUNT(A.Status)
    FROM    Ward_Master w ,
            IP_Admission a
    WHERE   a.Status = 'D'
            AND a.Ward_ID = w.Ward_ID

This statement is actually counting up all beds will `Status = 'D'` for *every* ward, with *no* correlation to the outside.  If there's more than 9, this will be (at least) a 2-digit number, at which point one of three things happens (I can't remember which off-hand):

1. The server throws an error because the number's two big to fit in the destination data type.
2. You get the first digit (from the start of the *string*, not the 1's digit).
3. You get the last digit (of the *string* - in math/number terms, the first digit/1's place).

---

That out of the way, lets build a better query.

First, we need some information from the master Ward table:

```
SELECT ward_Id, ward_Name, bed_Strength
FROM Ward_Master
```

... we also need some aggregated data from a secondary table.
This is a problem - if we do a simple join to the table, we need to include the columns from `Ward_Master` in the `GROUP BY`, which isn't preferable (as they aren't all likely to be on the same index).
Can we aggregate the data by itself?

```
SELECT ward_Id, SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_O,
                SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_D
FROM IP_Admission
WHERE status IN ('D', 'O')
GROUP BY ward_Id
```

This will total up all beds, per ward, with status `O` or `D`.
(The `WHERE` clause isn't *strictly* necessary, due to the `CASE` statements, but it makes the optimizer more likely to be able to use an index).
The `CASE` statements are being used to "split" the allowed values into two different columns.  We now have a single row per ward, so now we can combine our two queries (being mindful of name collisions):

```
SELECT Ward_Master.ward_Id, Ward_Master.ward_Name, Ward_Master.bed_Strength,
       Ward_Master.bed_Strength - COALESCE(Bed.status_O, 0) as free_Bed,
       COALECE(Bed.status_D, 0) as TBV
FROM Ward_Master
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ward_Id, SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_O,
                           SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'D' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS status_D
           FROM IP_Admission
           WHERE status IN ('D', 'O')
           GROUP BY ward_Id) Bed
       ON Bed.ward_Id = Ward_Master.ward_Id
```

(I'm no longer a fan of single-character table aliases.  The names you have here aren't terribly long, so just use them.  When you *do* need something shorter or sometimes longer, make it explanatory)
... and unless I've missed something, that's all you need.

Comment: Its a very nice explanation, it helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Here I added a subquery to return count with other data

```
SELECT  ( SELECT    COUNT(status)
          FROM      IP_Admission
          WHERE     Status = 'D'
                    AND ward_ID = A.ward_ID
        ) ,
        M.Ward_ID ,
        M.Ward_Name ,
        M.Bed_Strength ,
        M.Bed_Strength - ISNULL(COUNT(A.WARD_id), 0) AS Free_Bed ,
        ISNULL(COUNT(A.Status), 0) AS TBV
FROM    Ward_Master M
        LEFT OUTER  JOIN IP_Admission A ON A.WARD_ID = M.WARD_ID
                                           AND ( A.Status = 'O' )
                                           OR A.Status IN ( SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(1), COUNT(A.Status)) AS TBV
                                                            FROM    Ward_Master w ,
                                                                    IP_Admission a
                                                            WHERE   a.Status = 'D'
                                                                    AND a.Ward_ID = w.Ward_ID )
GROUP BY M.Ward_ID ,
        M.Bed_Strength ,
        M.Ward_Name ,
        A.Status
```